# I am not able to get spring in the simulation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, animation, shared-memory

I am simulating spring-mass system. This is the code.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
k = 1
m = 1
def f(x, u, t):
    return -k/m*x

x_graph = []
t_graph = []
u_graph = []
y_graph = []

def func(x_0, u_0, t_0, h):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        m1 = h*u_0
        k1 = h*f(x_0, u_0, t_0)
        m2 = h*(u_0 + 0.5*k1)
        k2 = h*f(x_0+0.5*m1, u_0+0.5*k1, t_0+0.5*h)
        m3 = h*(u_0 + 0.5*k2)
        k3 = h*f(x_0+0.5*m2, u_0+0.5*k2, t_0+0.5*h)
        m4 = h*(u_0 + k3)
        k4 = h*f(x_0+m3, u_0+k3, t_0+h)
        x_0 += (m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4)/6
        u_0 += (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
        t_0 += h
        x_graph.append(x_0)
        t_graph.append(t_0)
        u_graph.append(u_0)
        y_graph.append(0)
    return x_0



print(func(0, 5, np.pi, 0.01))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set(xlim=(-5.1, 5.1), ylim=(-0.05,1))
# ax.grid()
def animate(i):
    l1.set_data(x_graph[:i],y_graph[:i])
    return l1,

l1, = ax.plot([],[], 'o-',markevery=[-1])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,frames=len(t_graph),interval =5, blit=True)
# plt.show()
ani.save('pandemic.gif', writer='ffmpeg')
```

I want to have a spring at point (-5,0) which changes its position as the block moves. My current output is this[image]
Edit1:- I have added code which includes data for x_graph, y_graph and t_graph.

Comment: mind sharing t_graph, x_graph and y_graph data?

Comment: @Amit Added. Check it

Comment: Thank you ..Trying to understand your code. I see your l2 and l3 are empty throughout .. What is the purpose of l2 and l3?

Comment: Also you are creating t_graph and u_graph but not using it .. is it for downstream code?

Comment: It is unclear from your description on what you want to achieve, if you want to plot the vector look at arrow or plot from the origin to the point.

Comment: Please elaborate the problem background in detail!

Comment: @Amit t_graph and u_graph are part of other code

Comment: @sai I'm simulating spring-mass system having spring coefficient 1N/m and of mass 1 kg. Now, the object is the ball moving in the gif and I want to have a line whose length changes as the object moves

Comment: @Arnav Slightly spring like solution added. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct answer has already been provided. I am adding a different solution. This solution will suit if the spring is attached on the left to a rigid wall and the ball is moving. The spring stretches and compresses based on the distance between the wall and the ball. This looks like below.

[image: Harmonic Spring Motion GIF]

I changed your code very slightly to do this. Please beware that some of the values are hard coded so one has to change them to suit the requirement. It is very easy to change them depending on the x_lim values.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation

k = 1
m = 1
def f(x, u, t):
    return -k/m*x

x_graph = []
t_graph = []
u_graph = []
y_graph = []

def func(x_0, u_0, t_0, h):
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        m1 = h*u_0
        k1 = h*f(x_0, u_0, t_0)
        m2 = h*(u_0 + 0.5*k1)
        k2 = h*f(x_0+0.5*m1, u_0+0.5*k1, t_0+0.5*h)
        m3 = h*(u_0 + 0.5*k2)
        k3 = h*f(x_0+0.5*m2, u_0+0.5*k2, t_0+0.5*h)
        m4 = h*(u_0 + k3)
        k4 = h*f(x_0+m3, u_0+k3, t_0+h)
        x_0 += (m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4)/6
        u_0 += (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
        t_0 += h
        x_graph.append(x_0)
        t_graph.append(t_0)
        u_graph.append(u_0)
        y_graph.append(0)
    return x_0



print(func(0, 5, np.pi, 0.01))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set(xlim=(-5.1, 5.1), ylim=(-1,1))
# ax.grid()
def animate(i):
    l1.set_data(x_graph[:i],y_graph[:i])
    sin_x = []
    sin_y = []
    for j in np.linspace(-5,x_graph[i],250):
        sin_x.append(j)
        sin_y.append(0.15*np.sin((j+5)*(2*np.pi)*10/(x_graph[i]+5)))
    l2.set_data(sin_x, sin_y)
    return l1,l2,

l1, = ax.plot([],[], 'o',markevery=[-1])
l2, = ax.plot([],[], '-')


ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=len(t_graph),interval =0.5, blit=True)
# plt.show()
ani.save('pandemic.gif', writer='imagemagic')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to simulate a mass osculating around a point.

This small edit should work

[image]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
k = 1
m = 1
def f(x, u, t):
    return -k/m*x


def func(x_0, u_0, t_0, h):
    x_graph = []
    t_graph = []
    u_graph = []
    y_graph = []
    for i in range(1, 1000):
        m1 = h*u_0
        k1 = h*f(x_0, u_0, t_0)
        m2 = h*(u_0 + 0.5*k1)
        k2 = h*f(x_0+0.5*m1, u_0+0.5*k1, t_0+0.5*h)
        m3 = h*(u_0 + 0.5*k2)
        k3 = h*f(x_0+0.5*m2, u_0+0.5*k2, t_0+0.5*h)
        m4 = h*(u_0 + k3)
        k4 = h*f(x_0+m3, u_0+k3, t_0+h)
        x_0 += (m1 + 2*m2 + 2*m3 + m4)/6
        u_0 += (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4)/6
        t_0 += h
        x_graph.append(x_0)
        t_graph.append(t_0)
        u_graph.append(u_0)
        y_graph.append(0)
    return  t_graph, x_graph, y_graph, u_graph 

t, x, y, u = func(0, 5, np.pi, 0.01)


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set(xlim=(-5.1, 5.1), ylim=(-0.05,1))
# ax.grid()
def animate(i):
    i, j = [0, x[i]], [0, y[i]]
    l1.set_data(i, j)
    return l1,

l1, = ax.plot([],[], 'o-',markevery=[-1])
l2, = ax.plot([],[], 'o-',markevery=[-1])
l3, = ax.plot([],[], 'o-',markevery=[-1])

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate,frames=len(t),interval =5, blit=True)
fig.show()
ani.save('pandemic.mp4', writer='ffmpeg')
```

Comment: No, What I'm trying to achieve is having a line (like a spring) which changes its length as the object moves

Comment: Did you checkout the animation above @Arnav?

Comment: If that's not it, for future reference the original post lacks clarity. Have a look at the guides for providing [MIVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).